# Error enabling WiFi dongle in linux system

Tags: linux, kernel, wifi

I'm having difficulties for quite awhile enabling a WiFi dongle driver in a Kernel 3.16.1 system. I've managed to install the driver after compiling the kernel (used the modprobe command with no issue) however I'm still getting the following errors:

**When executing 'ifconfig wlan1 up' or 'ifup wlan1':**

```
r8188eu 2-3:1.0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
r8188eu 2-3:1.0: Falling back to user helper
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
```

**iwconfig:**

`wlan1     unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Auto  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated

          Sensitivity:0/0

          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0`

**iwlist scan:**

```
wlan1     No scan results
```

I would greatly appreciate any help in this matter. Obviously /etc/network/interfaces is set correctly since this isn't the first time I've worked with WiFi USB dongles on linux systems. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was missing the firmware binary of the driver.

**Solution:**

```
sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/rtlwifi; sudo wget -O /lib/firmware/rtlwifi/rtl8188efw.bin https://github.com/OpenELEC/wlan-firmware/blob/master/firmware/rtlwifi/rtl8188efw.bin?raw=true
```

and reboot.